# Vue can not access props data

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a problem with Vue and component data function. It breaks even though all referenced prop data are correctly passed to the component and I can see them in vue-devtools. I am passing data from Laravel.

Vue Error:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in data(): "TypeError: Cannot read property 'isFavorited' of undefined"

found in

---> <FavBtn> at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/decimacen.cz/resources/assets/js/components/FavBtn.vue
       <Root>
```

FavBtn component:

```
<template>
    <a href="#" class="btn-link text-danger" v-on:click="ToggleFav">
        <i v-bind:class="{ 'fa fa-heart fa-2x': isFavorited == true, 'fa fa-heart-o fa-2x': isFavorited == false }" class="" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
</template>

<script>
    export default {

        name: 'FavBtn',

        props: ['fav'],

        data(){
            return{

                isFavorited: this.fav.isFavorited,
                favoritable_id: this.fav.favoritable_id,
            }
        },

        methods: {
            ToggleFav: function () {
                this.AjaxRequest();
                this.ToggleDOM();
            },

            ToggleDOM: function () {
                this.isFavorited = !(this.isFavorited);
            },

            AjaxRequest: function () {
                if (this.isFavorited)
                {
                    axios.delete('favorites/' + this.favoritable_id)
                }

                else {
                    axios.post('favorites/' + this.favoritable_id);
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Here is how I use the compnent in view:

```
<fav-btn v-bind:fav="{{ $user_store }}"></fav-btn>
```

All I want to know is if I have any mistakes in my code. Thanks.

**Edit**

Source:

```
<fav-btn v-bind:fav="{&quot;favoritable_id&quot;:3,&quot;favoritable_type&quot;:&quot;App\\Store&quot;,&quot;created_at&quot;:&quot;2017-05-24 16:12:33&quot;,&quot;updated_at&quot;:&quot;2017-05-24 16:12:33&quot;,&quot;deleted_at&quot;:null,&quot;isFavorited&quot;:true,&quot;pivot&quot;:{&quot;user_id&quot;:1,&quot;favoritable_id&quot;:3},&quot;users&quot;:[{&quot;id&quot;:1,&quot;email&quot;:&quot;hagen@wagen.cz&quot;,&quot;permissions&quot;:[],&quot;last_login&quot;:&quot;2017-05-25 13:38:38&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Franta Hagen&quot;,&quot;currency_id&quot;:1,&quot;sid&quot;:&quot;1400076495925ae8d480b95925ae8d480c3&quot;,&quot;created_at&quot;:&quot;2017-05-24 16:02:21&quot;,&quot;updated_at&quot;:&quot;2017-05-25 13:38:38&quot;,&quot;deleted_at&quot;:null,&quot;pivot&quot;:{&quot;favoritable_id&quot;:3,&quot;user_id&quot;:1}}]}"></fav-btn>
```

Comment: Is $user_store a laravel variable?

Comment: @Bert Yes it is.

Comment: What does it render?

Comment: Chances are it's a timing issue: initially, the prop is coming in as null. Check for its existence before assigning it: `isFavorited: this.fav && this.fav.isFavorited` (and similarly for favoritable_id)

Comment: @RoyJ I assigned the data as you suggested for isFavorited and did the same for the favoritable_id but get the same error.

Comment: @M.Novotny I mean, could you add to your answer how the last line of your question renders in HTML when the page is rendered. Like, view the source of the page and copy that line and add it to your question.

Comment: @M.Novotny that's the vue rendered button. I mean even before vue gets hold of it. Right click the page and view source and copy that line.

Comment: @M.Novotny I don't see an error in anything posted so far. 
https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/OmqYRL?editors=1010

Comment: So I have just deleted the public assests and recompiled them from scratch and it works... Laravel mix has probably gone too HAM on mixing things :-)